# Airflow Task failure/retry workflow

Tags: airflow

I have retry logic for tasks and it's not clear how Airflow handles task failures when retries are turned on.

Their [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=on_failure_callback) just states that `on_failure_callback` gets triggered when a task fails, but if that task fails and is also marked for retry does that mean that both the `on_failure_callback` and `on_retry_callback` would be called?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Retry logic/parameters will take place before failure logic/parameters. So if you have a task set to retry twice, it will attempt to run again two times (and thus executing `on_retry_callback` ) before failing (and then executing `on_failure_callback`).

An easy way to confirm the sequence that it is executed in is to set your `email_on_retry` and `email_on_failure` to `True` and see the order in which they appear. You can physically confirm that it will retry before failing.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 2, 8),
    'email': ['you@work.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}
```

Comment: thank you! this totally helped. i appreciate the explanation and the steps I can take to confirm!

Comment: @genhernandez no problem! Happy to help.

Comment: A separate question to this, if we do not set the retry_delay parameter, but set the retries parameter, what would be the default retry_delay, I have verified that it does work with passing the retry_delay value but do not have an insight on what the default value is.Thanks

Comment: @AkashShah 
`retry_delay: timedelta = timedelta(seconds=300)` according to the docs here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator