# How to persist a value during airflow retry

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Everytime a dag triggers a task I would like to generate a value and keep the value during retry (if the task fails to run for any reason)

I try to declare a variable inside the dag (basically set current time to the variable)
When the task fails and it retries, it set the variable with latest time again

Answer (score 0):

- You can make use of [`on_failure_callback` and `on_retry_callback` params](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2419) of `BaseOperator` to push the value that you want to persist as [`xcom`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms)
- Thereafter, you can [retrieve that data from `Xcom`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3173) in any `task` across any `DAG` of your `Airflow` deployment, including the *retry attempt of same / different `task`*

---

Also have a look at

- [Can a failed Airflow DAG Task Retry with changed parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54223655/3679900)
- [Airflow Task failure/retry workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54598163/3679900)

Comment: "including the retry attempt of same / different task" - do you have a working implementation of that? My experimentation, and sources [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-dev/201809.mbox/%3cCAERDx9eKTwU5Urq+pnq_8Q-hb-nHtFNq_xwkGGpxVo4MhB_Brg@mail.gmail.com%3e) and [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6370), suggest that xcom is cleared before execution.

Comment: did you find a way to do that in the end @scubbo ?